# Student with NO certification

Tags: sql, sql-server

Student

```
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | First Name| Last Name    |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | John      | A            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | Jane      | B            |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

Certifications

```
+----+------------------+
| id | Name             |
+----+------------------+
| 1  | Certification 1  |
+----+------------------+
| 2  | Certification 2  |
+----+------------------+
| 3  | Certification 3  |
+----+------------------+
```

StudentCertifications

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id | StudentID  | CertificationID |
+----+------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 1          | 1               |
+----+------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 1          | 2               |
+----+------------+-----------------+
| 3  | 1          | 3               |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

What I Want to find through SQL Query :

StudentMissingCertifications

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id | StudentID  | CertificationID |
+----+------------+-----------------+
| 1  | 2          | 1               |
+----+------------+-----------------+
| 2  | 2          | 2               |
+----+------------+-----------------+
| 3  | 2          | 3               |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That formatting was unreadable. Legend

Comment: Read about `not in (....)`. Simple enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When posting a question, you need to actually ask question (seem rather obvious doesn't it :) ). Have a look at the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) page on how to ask a question. Also you might want to have a look at [Forum  Etiquette: How to post sample data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: Sorry my fault, Was working on the formatting myself though Yogesh was fast :)

Comment: @Ram, have a read of this: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Check my answer @RamKumar

Comment: Thanks, guys, Realized it was so simple after gone through all your answer. Not sure where my mind today. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your problem:

```
select Student.id,[First Name],[Last Name],Certifications.id,name
from Student cross join Certifications
left join StudentCertifications
on 
Student.id=StudentCertifications.Studentid
WHERE StudentCertifications.Studentid IS NULL
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id  First_Name  Last_Name   id     name
2   Jane         B          1    Certification 1
2   Jane         B          2    Certification 2
2   Jane         B          3    Certification 3
```

Please follow the link for demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/866ce/16

Answer (score 3):

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM Studients S CROSS JOIN Certifications C
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
  SELECT 1 FROM StudentCertifications SC WHERE SC.StudentId=S.Id AND SC.CertificationID=C.Id
 )
```

Or  using `EXCEPT`

```
SELECT S.ID,C.ID FROM Studients S CROSS JOIN Certifications C
EXCEPT 
SELECT StudentId, CertificationID FROM StudentCertifications
```

Answer (score 1):

Link all students with all certifications via `CROSS JOIN` then filter the ones that he already has with `NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT
    StudentID = S.ID,
    MissingCertificationID = C.ID
FROM
    Student AS S
    CROSS JOIN Certifications AS C
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'student does not have the certification'
        FROM
            StudentCertifications X
        WHERE
            X.StudentID = S.ID AND
            X.CertificationID = C.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cross join to get all possible student/certifications, then left join to the student certificate table where the result is null.

```
select
    s.Id as studentId,
    s.Name as studentName,
    c.Id as certId,
    c.name as certName
from 
    #student s
cross join #cert c
left join #studentCert sc on s.Id = sc.studentId and c.Id = sc.certId
where
    sc.studentId is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the `join`s (i.e. `LEFT JOIN`) to find the students which have still not any certificates

```
select 
       s.id as StudentID, c.id as CertificationID  
from Student s
left join StudentCertifications sc on sc.StudentID = s.id
cross join (select id from Certifications) c
where sc.StudentID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well the question, this query is what you're looking for

```
SELECT First Name, Last Name FROM Student
WHERE Student.id NOT IN (SELECT StudentID From StudentCertifications)
```